# Variable - From Apache, via proxy, to Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have a Rails application. The application is accessible via Passenger on Apache. Furthermore, I have a second configuration on Apache that use `ProxyPass` to the first. It works. The problem is I don't know how to pass a variable from the second one to the very application.

It looks the `SetEnv` doesn't work.

Comment: mod_rewrite can set application-accessible environment variables using the flag `[E=varname:varvalue]` but I am not sure how they behave with ProxyPass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by adding a request header.

```
RequestHeader add <NAME> <VALUE>
```